# Reading and processing input

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

Write a program that calculates and displays the take-home pay for a commissioned sales employee after deductions are taken. The employee receives 7% of his or her total sales as his or her gross pay. His or her federal tax rate is 18%. He or she contributes 10% to his or her retirement program and 6% to Social Security. Use the Processing Logic provided in Step 2 below as a guide. The program's output should look something like this:

```
Enter weekly sales: 28,000
Total sales:    $28,000.00
Gross pay (7%): $1,960.00
Federal tax paid:   $352.80
Social security paid:   $117.60
Retirement contribution:    $196.00
Total deductions:   $666.40

Take home pay:  $1,293.60
Press any key to continue.
```

//Here is my Code, I am having trouble getting input

```
        //Declarations

        int weeklySales;
        double grossPay = weeklySales * .07;
        double fedTax = grossPay * .18;
        double retirement = grossPay * .1;
        double socSecurity = grossPay * .06;
        double totDeductions = socSecurity + retirement + fedTax;
        double takeHomePay = grossPay - totDeductions;

        //Promt user for Input
        System.Console.WriteLine("What is your weekly Sales?");
        weeklySales = Console.Read();
        System.Console.ReadLine();




         //Output Display
        System.Console.Write("\nYour Weekly Sale amount is :\t\t" + weeklySales+ "\n\nGross Pay:\t\t\t\t" + grossPay+ "\n\nFed Tax \t\t\t\t" + fedTax + "\n\nRetirement\t\t\t\t"+ retirement + "\n\nSocial Security:\t\t\t" + socSecurity + "\n\nTotal Deductions:\t\t\t" + totDeductions + "\n\nMaking your take home pay:\t\t" + takeHomePay);
        System.Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: "*I am having trouble getting input*" is also not a helpful description of your problem.

Comment: You gave us a problem statement (verbatim, I think) and you splashed your code in front of us to study.  That is not how this site works.  Please ask specific questions.

Comment: At least specify the clear description of your problem...

Comment: My apologies for not posting this correctly this is my first time here.

Comment: Basically I am having trouble asking the user "What is there weekly Sales amount" and storing that data into weeklySales for the calculation process to begin. At least thats what I think my only problem is, then again I could be wrong.

Comment: I am suppose to prompt the user for any amount they decide to enter, and my coding is suppose to calculate all their deductions and display them on the screen.

Comment: Please reduce your post to your particular question and don't post a complete problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Proper method:

```
Int32 weeklySales = 0;

while (weeklySales.Equals(0))
{
    Console.WriteLine("What are your weekly sales?");
    String input = Console.ReadLine();

    try
    {
        weeklySales = Int32.Parse(input);
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("There is an error in your input, try again!");
    }
}

Double grossPay = weeklySales * .07;
Double fedTax = grossPay * .18;
Double retirement = grossPay * .1;
Double socSecurity = grossPay * .06;
Double totDeductions = socSecurity + retirement + fedTax;
Double takeHomePay = grossPay - totDeductions;

Console.Write("\nYour Weekly Sale amount is :" + weeklySales + "$\nGross Pay: " + grossPay + "$\nFed Tax: " + fedTax + "$\nRetirement: " + retirement + "$\nSocial Security: " + socSecurity + "$\nTotal Deductions: " + totDeductions + "$\nMaking your take home pay: " + takeHomePay + "$");
Console.Read();
```

Easy method:

```
Console.WriteLine("What are your weekly sales?");

try
{
    Int32 weeklySales = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

    Double grossPay = weeklySales * .07;
    Double fedTax = grossPay * .18;
    Double retirement = grossPay * .1;
    Double socSecurity = grossPay * .06;
    Double totDeductions = socSecurity + retirement + fedTax;
    Double takeHomePay = grossPay - totDeductions;

    Console.Write("\nYour Weekly Sale amount is :" + weeklySales + "$\nGross Pay: " + grossPay + "$\nFed Tax: " + fedTax + "$\nRetirement: " + retirement + "$\nSocial Security: " + socSecurity + "$\nTotal Deductions: " + totDeductions + "$\nMaking your take home pay: " + takeHomePay + "$");
    Console.Read();
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("There is an error in input. Program will be terminated.");
}
```

Comment: You know... no one is forcing you to follow me on every thread I reply to just to criticize my code because you have nothing better to do ^_^

Comment: Haha. Honestly mate, believe it or not, this was all pure coinsidence, I saw you post yesterday on the same question I was posting, and two times today. I guess we're following eachother lol. The answer is somewhat better now btw.

Comment: Zarathos your a genius my friend. Your help made my code work. Thank you so much. But This is my fist week of class taking C# and I don't believe I should be using WHILES yet. Isn't there a simpler way, I mean for a beginner perspective

Comment: @user1974606 If this is your first week mate, then you can forget about my answer, 'cause that will be far too advanced. I would suggest looking at HenkHolterman 's answer!

Comment: How do you format currency with Dollar Symbols. And where would I have to insert it for all my deduction results

Comment: You can just add it to your summary output where it's needed in form of a string, and yes, it would be better to append it!

Comment: I did try HenkHoltermans answer, but it was not complete leaving room for me to figure out the rest, but what he doesn't know is that I have been stuck on this problem for days.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on "append it", and what it would look like please 
:)

Comment: I edit my answer to also provide an easier method now.

Comment: Where does the question go? "Please enter your weekly Sales amount", and how.

Answer (score 3):

```
  weeklySales = Console.Read();
```

Is not going to do what you think it does. It will return the ASCII value of the first char.

Instead:

```
  string weeklySalesText = Console.ReadLine();
  weeklySales = int.Parse(weeklySalesText );  // may need more processing.
```

Comment: `weeklySales` is an `int`. The rest of the code is fine though.

Comment: Right. Glossed over that, fixed now.

Comment: So your implying I should declare weeklySales as a string? Let me try your snippet of code

Comment: Note that the string is an extra (intermediate) variable.

Comment: @user1974606 No he isn't, he is just saying you should create a temporary variable `weeklySalesText` which should be a `string`.

Comment: I removed that piece of code with the one you provided me with and there were a couple of errors. Can you please tell me how to format currency

Comment: _"and there were a couple of errors."_  is not answerable. Use the edit link under the question, add the changed code at the bottom and be specific about the new errors.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to calculate the result using the variable before you put anything in the variable, that doesn't work. Do the input before you calculate the result.

Comment: That's true, but the input logic isn't correct either.

Comment: I get you. I should move //Prompt the user to the top

Answer (score 0):

`Console.Read()` doesn't do what you think it does. It gets the first new character, and returns it as an `int`. It doesn't read the whole line. Also, the `Console.ReadLine()` call after that is completely meaningless, since you're not doing anything with the result.

I think you want the user to write a line, and then capture the contents of that line, check if it's and `int`, if it's not write an error message and try again, and if it is, do stuff with it.

This is done as such:

```
while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out weeklySales))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Input was not a number.");
}
```

Replace

```
weeklySales = Console.Read();
System.Console.ReadLine();
```

With that, and afterwards, you can use `weeklySales` to calculate all other required variables.

Also, the definitions at the start shouldn't work either, as weeklySales isn't initialized at the start.

---

**EDIT:** As a little explanation how my method works: you are calling `int.TryParse(string, out int)`, which returns `false` if it the given string is not a number, and else parses it to an int and returns `true`.

The thing you want to parse to an integer is the console input, therefore, the first parameter should be `Console.ReadLine()`. `weeklySales` is obviously the number you want to convert the `string` to, and is therefore provided as an `out` parameter (look that up if you don't know what that is).

If `int.TryParse` returns `false` (and has therefore failed), we run the while loop to inform the user, and ask again. If not, then we continue the program.

Comment: So I should rearrange my prompt at the top and my declarations below?

Comment: @user1974606 First you should declare `int weeklySales`, then insert my piece of code (the while loop with `int.TryParse`), and then all your other calculations based on `weeklySales`.