# An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll error when using Parse

Tags: c#, parsing

Newcomer to the world of programming, have to do the assignment listed here: [Reading and processing input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14306562/reading-and-processing-input)

Now, I've finally wrapped my head around how to write the code (seen below), but I keep on getting "An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll. Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format." when I try to run my program. It keeps flagging up on "gross = double.Parse(inputvaluetwo);", which is presume might be due to there not being an input there. Could anyone please help?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace SalesProgram
{
    class SalesProgram
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            double sales;
            double gross;
            double retirement;
            double social;
            double tax;
            string inputvalue;
            string inputvaluetwo;
            string inputvaluethree;
            string inputvaluefour;
            string inputvaluefive;
            string name;
            Console.Write("Enter your name: ");
            name = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("How much did you sell in dollars? ");
            inputvalue = Console.ReadLine();
            sales = double.Parse(inputvalue);
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine("Your gross pay is");
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine(sales * 0.07);
            inputvaluetwo = Console.ReadLine();
            gross = double.Parse(inputvaluetwo);
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine("Your retirement deduction is:");
            Console.WriteLine(gross * 0.15);
            inputvaluethree = Console.ReadLine();
            retirement = double.Parse(inputvaluethree);
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine("Your tax deduction is:");
            Console.WriteLine(gross * 0.18);
            inputvaluefour = Console.ReadLine();
            tax = double.Parse(inputvaluefour);
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine("Your social security deduction is:");
            Console.WriteLine(gross * 0.09);
            inputvaluefive = Console.ReadLine();
            social = double.Parse(inputvaluefive);
            Console.ReadKey();
            Console.WriteLine("Finally, your take-home, or net pay, is:");
            Console.WriteLine(gross-retirement-tax-social);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: use ``double.TryParse()`` for it

Comment: What is the vlaue of `inputvaluetwo` and what is your `CurrentCulture`? Debug your code and tell us?

Comment: inputvaluetwo is supposed to be sales*0.07, which then gets converted to double through the aforementioned parse command.

Have no clue what CurrentCulture is, only three weeks into the course.

Comment: @AB Can you please tell what is the value of `inputvaluetwo` exactly when you debug your code?

Answer (score 0):

It means there's an incorrect string value somewhere. Use this instead :

```
double retirement ;
if(double.TryParse(inputvaluethree, out retirement) == false)
{
    Console.Write("Error on inputvaluethree : " + inputvaluethree);
}
```

Comment: And presumably the same format for the other doubles? (gross, tax, social)?

Comment: The goal is to find what values are causing this Exception, so yes implements this pattern for each of your Parse.

Answer (score 0):

It means the string you entered can not be converted to double.

Use following snippet

```
if (Double.TryParse(string, out inputvalue))
{
  //do any additional stuff you want to with this inputvalue
}
else
{
  //do what you want to do if conversion fails
}
```

This overload differs from the Double.Parse(String) method by returning a Boolean value that indicates whether the parse operation succeeded instead of returning the parsed numeric value. It eliminates the need to use exception handling to test for a FormatException in the event that string is invalid and cannot be successfully parsed.

For more details you can go to following link

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx